# How to persist following associative data to the db using doctrine?

Tags: symfony, laravel, doctrine-orm

> I use 2 tables.They are shift and fuel issues. Data come from front
>   end with association itself.Now I need to send those data to mysql db
>   using doctrine.Front end data structure is like following.

```
 {
"commenceTime": "2015-11-06T02:01:12+0000",
"endTime": "2015-11-06T02:01:12+0000",
"amountGiven" : 50505,
"pumperId":2,
"issuedLooseFuel" : 
    [
        {
            "amount" : 1500.00
        },
        {
            "amount" : 2500.00
        }
    ]
 }
```

now.cleary I want to send shift details as

```
{"commenceTime": "2015-11-06T02:01:12+0000",
"endTime": "2015-11-06T02:01:12+0000",
"amountGiven" : 50505,
"pumperId":2}
```

and 
fuel details as =>

```
 "issuedLooseFuel" : 
    [
        {
            "amount" : 1500.00
        },
        {
            "amount" : 2500.00
        }
    ]
```

fuel details must be add to the db with references of shift id.

so first must send the shift data and return the shift id and then send the fuel_issue data according to the returned shift ID.
What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in orm use entity relationship.

```
$shift = new Shift();
// fill shift object
$issuedLooseFuel=new IssuedLooseFuel();
// fill  $issuedLooseFuel
$shift->setIssuedLooseFuel([$issuedLooseFuel]);//one2many relation, cascade persist
$em->persist($shift);
$em->flush();
```